# Which one out of a keto group or a hydroxyl group would get protonated first if both are present in a compound (attachment)

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, carbonyl-compounds, alcohols, phenols

[image: This is the question]

In the solution provided by my teacher he protonated the ketone, moved the +ve above by resonance did methyl shift and then did dehydration to form a benzene type system. Is this only because for this particular care aromaticity was being obtained or is the keto group always first protonated
[image: this is the solution]

Comment: It's generally a valid question to ask which gets preferentially protonated, but in this particular case, it actually doesn't matter at all. Protonation and deprotonation at oxygen is fast and happens all the time; if the proton gets onto the "wrong" oxygen (i.e. the hydroxyl group), it can't do anything apart from fall off again, so it just falls off and tries again.

Comment: @orthocresol So is there no standardized way to predict it theoretically rather than just hit and trial ?

Comment: It’s “trial and error”; and there are pKa values, you can look them up, so there is a “theoretical” way, but it’s simply not relevant for your question.